# Dropdown Menu won't show over the next section in Elementor

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

So I am using elementor. I used a wordpress menu in elementor editor it shows correctly, but on the actual page the dropdown goes "under" the background of the first section, or better said, it simply cuts at the top margin of the first section.

[How it is on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUOsA.png)
[How it is in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucUPA.png)

I tried the next custom css applied but didn't work (or any other css I tried):

```css
selector .sub-menu .elementor-nav-menu--dropdown .sm-nowrap{
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I also made sure the background are not set to opacity 0. Also, I tried increasing the z-index of the header but nothing.

Comment: You should provide html and CSS and the link where it can be inspected would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having a z-index issue.
You might want to try some of these:

Inspect the elements: use the browser's developer tools.
Check for the z-index values of the **header**, the **first section** and also the **dropdown** menu to understand the stacking order.

You could also try to **set an higher z-index for the dropdown**:

```css
.elementor-nav-menu .sub-menu {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Or set the **posizione** and **z-index** of the parent elements:

```css
.header-selector {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Also check for any conflicting css rules.

Comment: Neither of these two worked. Didn't find any conflicting css either...